# What can cause a Droid Incredible to stop connecting to a PC via USB?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-droid-incredible, usb-connection-mode

When I connect my phone to my laptop via USB, it is able to charge, but I am not able to mount it as a drive. Neither my computer nor my phone recognize that there is a device plugged in. This happened within the past few days, and I don't think that I changed anything on either side.

I already checked the settings and USB debugging is on, USB debugging notify is on, and Stay awake is on in the Development settings menu. I also tried rebooting both devices to see if that would fix it, but it hasn't.

My phone is a Droid Incredible running CM7.0.3. My laptop is running Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing usb cable. Bad cables can cause this (at least I had this problem once, which went away simply by using another cable).

Comment: Unfortunately, I only own the one cable. I'll borrow a friend's cable later and check. I hope it's this simple.

Comment: This turned out to be it. However, I had to try about 3 USB cables before I found out. Annoying...

Answer (score 1):

It could also be that Windows 7 or the BIOS disabled that USB port...possibly due to something power related.  Have you switched the USB port you're plugged into? Possibly try switching to another USB port.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that you've damaged some of the pins on the device's micro USB connector. If connecting it to another computer with another cable doesn't works I could recommend you to contact your dealer for repair :)

Comment: That's a good call, too. However, I tried multiple combinations of cords and computers. It's definitely my cord either not supporting data or being damaged.

Answer (score 0):

As another possibility (although you mention that you did not change anything on the PC): I had a similar problem once when I still had my PALM desktop software (and synchronization software) installed on my PC.

After a log of searching I found out that the PALM sync software used the COMM4 port on my PC.

For some reason, the USB connection between my Galaxy S and my Windows 7 PC used the same port.

Once I uninstalled the PALM software, the USB connection worked flawlessly.

Maybe more technical people at this forum can explain why, but that's what I found out.